# Is there any way to change default font from fontawesome website

Tags: android, android-studio

I found some fonts from this site :

[Font Awesome Website](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)

i want to use these fonts to  add icons to the text,button etc... , But my question can I change default font?

Answer (score 1):

By default it doesn't add any icon to button? At least I'm not familiar with. If I did not correctly understand your question, please inform me.

If you want, you can change default font color by adding `font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;` (value can be different).

If you want to change for specific buttons, you can add a class to them and then:

```
.new-class {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

__

Taken from:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp